autorun script in bash for minecraft
I'm attempting to write a script in bash to run a script (run.sh) when a pgrep -f minecraft does not return anything.
!#/bin/bash
status=false
while :
do
        pgrep -f minecraft && status=true
        if $status = true; then
                echo "up"
        else
                echo "down"
                echo "restarting in 10 seconds, pres CTRL + C to cancel"

                sleep 10
                ./run.sh
        fi
done

This I expected to run run.sh when it could not find the process for minecraft.
Instead of detecting it live If the script is running and the process changes status, either grom existing to not or vice versa it will keep outputting what it was before the change.

Please paste your script at shellcheck.net and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Try if pgrep minecraft; then ...

Nowadays, consider writing a systemd  service file and using systemd to manage services..

The minimal fix is #! instead of !# and if [ "$status" = "true" ] though as suggested in a previous comment, if pgrep -f minecraft is much better. Tangentially see also Why is testing $? to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?

Really, don't do this at all. As others have said -- make a systemd service. You don't need to use pgrep or any equivalent to it when you're doing proper process supervision, because the thing you're supervising just runs as a direct child of the supervisor. That means the supervisor is affirmatively notified when it shuts down, but can also do things like restart it, check its status, &c just by looking at its children; that's more reliable (can't incorrectly find different processes by the same name) and more efficient (doesn't need to scan the whole process tree).

@Saboteur, you mean & not && -- && doesn't create any background process at all, so it doesn't set $!. (If ./run.sh is a separate process that forks off a grandchild, that won't work for setting $! in the shell that invoked it). Then again, I still recommend setting up a proper systemd service rather than doing any of this.

Cyrus's comment to use shellcheck.net to fix it
#!/bin/bash
status=false
while :
do
        pgrep -f minecraft && status=true
        if [ $status = true ]; then
                echo "up"
        else
                echo "down"
                echo "restarting in 10 seconds, pres CTRL + C to cancel"

                sleep 10
                ./run.sh
        fi
done

The changes was:
!# -> #!
and  =  -> [ ]
Edit 1: Fixed the comparing syntax based on comments
Edit 2: Fixed shellcheck.com to shellcheck.net

This is not valid syntax. Or rather, you end up running either true [ ] true which nominally works (it runs true and ignores its arguments) or [ ] true which is a syntax error.

This was the solution it just wasn't the right syntax, thanks anyway i still used the equals instead of the [ ] and it works if its run from the same window the server is in

It's canonically shellcheck.net, not .com
